# JQuery Unit Testing tooltips (jasmine, qunit, etc..)

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, qunit

I was wondering if anyone could provide me information, perhaps some example code, on how to unit test tooltips?
 The framework is no issue, I am free to use any kind of Javascript/JQuery framework there is available (Jasmine, Qunit etc).
The hard part is that I can not really find a good example of how tooltips (which their scripts is called asynchronously) are tested.

So any example regarding unit testing JQuery UI tooltip or other external libraries (qtip etc) would be really helpfull.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery team uses Qunit for their testing.  When I work on jQuery plugins, I tend to use the same tools.  Here is an example test in Qunit:

```
//In your JS

function myTestFunction() {
  //code here
}

//In test.js

QUnit.test( 'My Tests: ', function( assert ) {

  'use strict';

  var $el = $('#my-tooltip');

  assert.strictEqual( typeof myFunction, 'function', 'It is a function.' );
  assert.notEqual( $el.css('display'), 'none', 'It is visible.' );

});
```

Comment: But is it also possible for example to check if the object (in my case tooltip) is visible with qunit? Do they have a function for that? Or should I just the visible selector?

Comment: You can do a check of the `display` property.  If it isn't `none`, then it is visible.  I will add an example.

Comment: Oke thank you! Another question, in my HTML file I have an object (div, span etc) which can triggers the tooltip function. But I can add parameters to my function like: onclick="Tooltip("content",width,500)". How do I for example check if the string "content" is used in my tooltip? Hope is not to much asked.

Comment: That's pretty specific to your plugin but I will take a guess.  Maybe,  grab the tooltip element and check its innerHTML and see if it contains "content".

Comment: Ah oke awesome! That really helped me. The only thing that I still have a question about is that I am using Qtip as plugin, but this plugin does not return anything within my function. It only triggers the Qtip event and shows the tooltip. Should my function return something or can I also test without return something (in your example above the `myTestFunction` does not return anything) ?

Comment: No your functions don't have to return anything.  For instance, you can check to see if qtip fires an event.  Check out the [api](http://api.qunitjs.com/).  There are a lot of things you can do.

Comment: Thank you so much. I am going to have a try. Thanks for your explanation. I will mark your answer!

Comment: Still I got just one question left. Is it also possible to actually have the "myTestFunction" in a separate file?

Comment: Yes.  Your test JS should be entirely separate from your regular JS. I just did it here to show it quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Jasmine supports asynchronous tests in general.  You can make your assertions in a callback and call `done()` to signify that your test successfully completed.

For example

```
it("should work with async", function(done) {
   doSomethingAsync().success(function() {
      // make assertions in callback
      done(); // done with test
   });
})
```

Comment: Could you perhaps explain how your example would work in combination if you have within your html a call like: `onclick="tooltip("content")"` and in the JS the  `function tooltip(){}` script and using the Jasmine test?